# Question about SQL select within left join

Tags: mysql

I have a question about my SQL code. My aim is to create a table2 containing all information about people who had ever had Y >=3 based on table1.

table1

```
ID Y date
A  1 2020-01-01
A  2 2020-01-02
A  3 2020-01-03
A  4 2020-01-04
B  1 2020-01-01
B  2 2020-01-02
C  1 2020-01-01
C  2 2020-01-02
C  3 2020-01-03
```

Table2

```
ID Y date
A  1 2020-01-01
A  2 2020-01-02
A  3 2020-01-03
A  4 2020-01-04
C  1 2020-01-01
C  2 2020-01-02
C  3 2020-01-03
```

My current SQL code:

```
select a.ID, b.* from 
      (select distinct ID from table1 
       where Y >2) as a 
left join table1 as b
on a.ID = b.ID;
```

It returns error 1064 saying that I have some syntax error.
Would someone kindly help me with this?

Comment: [edit] to quote the exact error including "near" description

Comment: There is no syntax error with the published code.

Comment: @P.Salmon Maybe you and the OP are on different MySQL versions, or perhaps are using different server settings.

Comment: No version of MySQL since 4.1 would report a syntax error for the above query. I guess the OP has not posted their code that gave an error. Or maybe they're not using MySQL.

Comment: I think your original query was completely fine.  Only issue I would think is the "as" clause.  I dont believe you need the "as" when applying the alias to a table name reference... ex: from (your query ) as a... just have as from (your query) a.  The "a" is implied alias after the subquery, or other table reference such as your "as b" for the second "table1" reference

Answer (score 0):

I would use exists logic here:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 t2
              WHERE t2.ID = t2.ID AND t2.Y >= 3);
```

On MySQL 8+, we can use analytic functions:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(Y >= 3) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) cnt
    FROM table 1
)

SELECT ID, Y, date
FROM cte
WHERE cnt > 0;
```

Comment: So would I but it doesn't explain to the OP why there is an error (if there is one)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I think I would need to use the left join because I have another table, table3. And I want to create table4 which all information of individuals whose Y >=3 in table1.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following

```
select * from table1 where id in
(select id from table1 where Y >=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

A JOIN works nicely...

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.* 
           FROM my_table a 
           JOIN my_table b 
             ON b.id = a.id 
          WHERE b.y >2;
```

Comment: This looks great. It will meet all my need for creating other tables. I'll try it out! Thank you!

Comment: You wouldn't typically store such easily derived data.

Comment: We actually plan to cut the data by SQL then feed into R to do modeling. So, I think I'll create a CSV file of the product. I rarely use MySQL. Thank you for your input!